# Организация корпоративного видеохостинга для файлов объемом более 10Гб

Tags: хостинг, видео, плеер

Поставлена задача организовать корпоративный ресурс для хранения видеофайлов большого объема, Full HD видео, длительностью 1-2 часа, итого один файл 10-20 Гб. Снижать качество нельзя. Резать файлы нельзя. Заливает оператор/монтажник, которому нужен самый простой вариант заливки (по http). Пользователей - мало, максимум 5-7 одновременных подключений по праздникам. Общий объем хранения - около 5Тб, с разрастанием до 10 в ближайший год.

Вопрос: что рекомендуете использовать для организации такого ресурса?

а) если готовый сервис (везде ограничение по размерам файла в 2Гб, кроме youtube, но на ютюбе слишком много приседаний надо сделать для получения разрешения от них, а забанить могут за одну жалобу), то какой?

б) если поднять свой хостинг на выделенном сервере/виртуалках, и поставить плеер и аплоад скрипт для заливки по хттп, то что посоветуете простое и незатейливое, но с учетом объема файлов и качества видео?

Comment: «Cнижать качество нельзя» — а что имеется ввиду? Всего скорее можно уменьшить объем без изменения качества как такового.  Full HD  (1080p) такой длительности вряд ли должно превышать 1 Гб.

Кажется, что поднятие своего сервиса для такого количества файлов — лишняя головная боль. Но некоторые товарищи рекомендуют такое: http://www.kernel-video-sharing.com/ru/